# Display a scientific notation in twig

Tags: php, filter, twig, scientific-notation

I'm trying to display a double with my twig template in a [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).
Any idea of a way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [format](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/format.html) filter with the formatter of the [sprintf](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) function, as example:

```
{% set foo = 0.00000000751  %}

{{ "Scientific notation: %e"|format(foo) }}

{{ "Scientific notation: %g"|format(foo) }}
```

> Scientific notation: 7.510000e-9
>
> Scientific notation: 7.51e-9

[Here](https://twigfiddle.com/rcnsml) a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to display only two number after the coma:

```
{{ ("%e"|format(mydouble)) |slice(0, 4)}}{{ ("%e"|format(mydouble)) [8:]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres another method, giving you the control over how many significant digits you want to show:

```
{{ 2.9999999999|format_scientific_number({min_significant_digits_used: 2,max_significant_digits_used: 6,rounding_mode: 'halfup'})|replace({'E0':''}) }}
```

First, you use `format_scientific_number()` with parameters.
Later you have to replace ugly E0, if it occurs.

To be able to use `format_scientific_number()`, you have to install twig extension, which is briefly described here:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format_number.html